# CRM 2011 Outlook Client open custom web app, both sites using ADFS authentication

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Currently I'm working on a task to fix the process of opening custom web page in outlook client from custom ribbon button, it's similar to this question:
[JavaScript pop-up in Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460559/javascript-pop-up-in-dynamics-crm-2011-outlook-)
client

However, I have configured the website to have the same authentication token from the same ADFS as CRM web. If I open it using IE/any other web browsers (in UR 12), it works fine. If I open it using outlook client, it keep prompting the user to authenticate (which is quite annoying for some users).

I've read these, but they are only applicable for CRM form, not custom web app:
[ADFS (CRM 2011) - Authentication Issue in Microsoft Outlook Client for CRM (Response.Redirect(...) & Window.Open(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832964/adfs-crm-2011-authentication-issue-in-microsoft-outlook-client-for-crm-resp)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx

Anyone have any idea on this?
FYI, I'm using CRM 2011 UR 12, and Outlook 2010 with CRM client.

TIA

Comment: Currently working on the same issue so will be keeping an eye on this or report back if I find something.

Comment: I have used openStdWin with improved results.  It now only asks the user to login the first time the custom page is opened and after that the credentials a cached and all works well.  Seems weird as to why the credentials is not cached as soon as you open Outlook since the CRM client toolbar is already logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended-up using openStdWin, based on: http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/12/jscript-pop-up-in-crm-402011-internet-explorer-vs-outlook.html and Dieter's comment. It still asked me to authenticate once, even though I've provided the login detail in outlook client setup.

The javascript function:

```
function openNewWindow(url) { 
var name = "newWindow"; 
var width = 800; 
var height = 600; 
var newWindowFeatures = "status=1"; 
var oldWindowFeatures = "width=800,height=600,status=1"; 
// Regular Jscript function to open a new window 
//window.open(url, name, oldWindowFeatures); 

// CRM function to open a new window 
openStdWin(url, name, width, height, newWindowFeatures); 
// CRM function to open a new window 
// with default CRM parameters 
//openStdWin(url, name); 
}
```